# Gradient of the Busemann function

Tags: differential-geometry

Im trying to show that the gradient of the Busemann function is unitary. The Busemann function has the next property

$|b(p) - b(q)| \leq d(p,q)$

And... with this property Cheeger said that

$|grad b |\leq 1$

I dont know why... because $d_p(q) = d(p,q)$ is not smooth at $p$ and I dont know how to conclude

Comment: Are you only dealing with the Cheeger-Gromoll splitting theorem case?  I think you need some additional assumption in the general case (to go from almost everywhere to everywhere), such as the nonexistence of conjugate points.

Comment: yess, i dont know why? But almost everywhere why is true?